# PHP post method

Tags: php, html

my code for welcome.php is as beow:

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

and the form :

```
<html>
<body>

     <form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
     Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

It should give the output my name and email id when I fill the form with my name and emailid .
but it is giving me the below error running the php file

```
Welcome 
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: name in C:\wamp\www\PHP Learning\welcome.php on line 4
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  236440  {main}( )   ..\welcome.php:0

Your email address is: 
( ! ) Notice: Undefined index: email in C:\wamp\www\PHP Learning\welcome.php on line 5
Call Stack
#   Time    Memory  Function    Location
1   0.0000  236440  {main}( )   ..\welcome.php:0
```

corresponding to that when I run html file which is supposed to give me the correct out, it only shows the

in the address bar I get this:

```
LH/PHP%20Learning/welcome_get.php?name=shailesh+kumar&email=shailblack%40gmail.com

Not Found///

The requested URL /PHP Learning/welcome_get.php was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.9 (Win64) PHP/5.5.12 Server at localhost Port 80
```

Please suggest where i m missing to execute the post method.

Comment: I didn't read the whole post, but you are trying to read POST on a `method="get"` form. That's a problem.

Comment: Plus, your action is named `welcome_get.php` and your page is named `welcome.php`.

Answer (score 1):

You are accessing POST variables directly but your form is submitted with the GET method.

By the way, you shouldn't **ever** use globals in the way that you have done in your example.

Answer (score 0):

change your php file to

```
<html>
<body>

    Welcome <?php echo isset($_POST["name"]) ? $_POST["name"] : ''; ?><br>
    Your email address is: <?php echo isset($_POST["email"]) ? $_POST["email"] : ''; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

When script is executed for the 1st time, the `$_POST` variable is empty array. Thats why you have got errors.

Then as others told you - change your method to post.

Comment: Thanks Seti .. I did exactly what u instructed but the values that i m filling in the box is not getting posted. Am I doing it wrong way? Please suggest.

Comment: name the file welcome.php and in the form also action change to welcome.php

Answer (score 0):

You method you use is `get`.

You must change that to `post`.

For more information, you can read [this](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp) article.

Answer (score 0):

you're using `<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">` to perform a `GET` request, but use `$_POST['name']` to get that value.

so try the example below

welcome.php

```
<html>
<body>

Welcome <?php echo $_POST["name"]; ?><br>
Your email address is: <?php echo $_POST["email"]; ?>

</body>
</html>
```

and the form:

```
<html>
<body>

     <form action="welcome.php" method="post">
     Name: <input type="text" name="name"><br>
      E-mail: <input type="text" name="email"><br>
    <input type="submit">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks Francis for the reply but the values are not getting passed on : my output as shown below after running the code you sent : Welcome 
Your email address is: it is not posting the values that i fill in the box.

Comment: @shaileshkumar I have tested it under PHP 5.3 with firefox and it worked functional, would u show me your test enviroment please?

Answer (score 0):

Your script is requesting the URL `welcome_get.php` but you named your file `welcome.php` - you need to change one of them. Your code is currently searching for a file that doesn't exist.

If you want to post use `method="POST"` not `method="get"`.

When you load the page your script looks for $_POST['name'] and $_POST['email']. What happens when you don't post any data? Well as you've seen you get errors.

Check that the variables exist before presenting them as you cannot guarantee their existence.

```
if(isset($_POST['email']) {
    echo $_POST['email'];
}
```

This will check to see if $_POST['email'] exists. If it does, it will echo its value, if it doesn't then it will show nothing.

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
<form action="welcome_get.php" method="get">
```

to

```
<form action="welcome_get.php" method="post">
```

as you are posting the values..Read more [here](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_httpmethods.asp)

and again, you dont have a file named `welcome_get.php` (i understood from the error you got). It should be `welcome.php`. so replace ypur `<form>` tag as follows

```
<form action="welcome.php" method="post">
```